# Which GTA V car has the best braking?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Just curious, does anyone know which car has the best braking stat in GTA V (viewable when you go to Los Santos Customs)?

Comment: Fortunately, IGN took care of all the busy work. Here is a [list of the vehicles complete with stats/prices](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Vehicles#Complete_GTA_5_Vehicles_List).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have compiled a list using the Brady guide for GTA 5.

---

First, let's define the vehicle categories with the best braking stats. According to the guide:

- **Ships** including the submarine, as well as all **Helicopters** have the maximum value of 10/10 for braking.
- **Bicycles** come in second with a maximum of 5 points,
- **Motorcycles** have a maximum of 4.5 points.
- **Cars**, with a maximum of 3.5 points (tuning/modding not included).
- **Planes** are dead last with 2.5 points for one plane only, all other planes have a measly score of 1 point (the minimum is 0.5 points, so they aren't quite dead last).

---

Now that we've established a hierarchy, let's talk about the top of each category.

Like I said before, all ships and helicopters have maximum score, so there's no point in listing the winners here.

Among the bicycles, there is one winner, the **BMX** with 5 points. Aside from the **Fixter** with its abysmal 0.5 points, all other bicycles have either 4 or 4.5 points.

The motorcycles category has quite a number of winners (with 4.5 points):

- **Dinka Double-T**,
- **Nagasaki Carbon RS**,
- **Pegassi Bati 801**,
- **Pegassi Bati 801RR**
- **Shitzu PCJ 600** .

Last place goes to the **Pegassi Faggio** with 1.5 points followed by the **Western Daemon** with 2 points. The rest range between 3.5 and 4 points.

Before we come to cars, I'd like to congratulate the (Crop) **Duster** for its "amazing" 2.5 points; the only plane to *not* score 1 point in braking.

Now comes the category everybody's been waiting for, the cars: Winners with 3.5 points are

- **HVY Barracks Semi** (surprisingly)
- **Canis Bodhi** (Trevor's car)
- **Nagasaki Blazer** (even though it behaves like a bike during crashes, it's got 4 wheels, so I consider it a car)
- **Dewbauchee Rapid GT**
- **Benefactor Surano**
- **Bravado Banshee**
- **Obey 9F**
- **Obey 9F Cabrio**
- **Coil Voltic** (the only car I know that's more or less silent)
- **Pegassi Vacca** and
- **Truffade Adder**

Dead last (with 0.5 points) are:

- **Dock Handler**,
- **HVY Dozer**,
- **Tank**,
- **Ripley**
- **(Golf) Caddy**.

Aside from the **JoBuilt Hauler**, the **JoBuilt Phantom** (both 2.5 points), the **Firetruck** (1.5 points) and the military **HVY Barracks Semi** (one of our winners), all trucks (including buses) have 1 point.

---

#### Disclaimer:

Please keep in mind that my answer is based off a work that is not related to Rockstar and may contain mistakes (I definitely found some while I used it).

Comment: You can upgrade the brakes on most of you cars you have listed ( basically none of the specials i.e. Firetruck ).

Comment: @Ramhound Good point, I added a `(tuning not included)` to make it clear that I'm only talking about non-modded vanilla cars, thanks :)